# Issue Opening Excel File in Spyder on Mac

Tags: python, pandas, excel, macos, spyder

I'm trying to open an excel file as a dataframe in Spyder on Mac using the typical method, seen below

```py
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_excel (r"/Users/myusername/Desktop/Test.xlsx")
print(df)
```

However, I keep getting the following error message:

Traceback (most recent call last):

```
  File ~/anaconda3/lib/python3.10/site-packages/IPython/core/async_helpers.py:129 in _pseudo_sync_runner
    coro.send(None)

  File ~/anaconda3/lib/python3.10/site-packages/IPython/core/interactiveshell.py:3260 in run_cell_async
    self.displayhook.exec_result = result

  File ~/anaconda3/lib/python3.10/site-packages/traitlets/traitlets.py:729 in __set__
    self.set(obj, value)

  File ~/anaconda3/lib/python3.10/site-packages/traitlets/traitlets.py:703 in set
    new_value = self._validate(obj, value)

  File ~/anaconda3/lib/python3.10/site-packages/traitlets/traitlets.py:735 in _validate
    value = self.validate(obj, value)

  File ~/anaconda3/lib/python3.10/site-packages/traitlets/traitlets.py:2144 in validate
    if isinstance(value, self.klass):  # type:ignore[arg-type]

TypeError: isinstance() arg 2 must be a type, a tuple of types, or a union

ERROR! Session/line number was not unique in database. History logging moved to new session 104
```

I have made sure openpyxl is installed, and have tried messing with the arguments in the pandas read_excel command
df = pd.read_excel (open('Test.xlsx', 'rb'),
sheet_name='Sheet3')

But still I get the error:

```
TypeError: isinstance() arg 2 must be a type, a tuple of types, or a union

ERROR! Session/line number was not unique in database. History logging moved to new session 109
```

Comment: how many sheets are in the excel workbook ?

Comment: also,  please provide a sample of the data given that this could be the cause.

Comment: I think it may actually be an issue with Spyder itself, not the excel sheet. I restarted anaconda and got this warning: 

You have missing dependencies!

# Mandatory:
pylsp >=1.7.2,<1.8.0 : 1.7.1 (NOK)

Please install them to avoid this message.

Comment: I was able to get it working, I restarted anaconda a bunch and also am now using this code:

import pandas as pd

# Specify the path to the Excel file
df = pd.read_csv('/Users/henryprice/Desktop/Test.csv', 'r', encoding="ISO-8859-1")
# Print the contents of the DataFrame
print(df)